# I was wondering whether it is acceptable to put the adverb “rudely” in the following three places in this sentence

Tags: adverbs

sentence: The man looked at me.
1 The man looked at me rudely.
2 The man rudely looked at me.
3 The man looked rudely at me.

Comment: This is the same as your other question.

Answer (score 1):

They should all be acceptable.